# How to fix this typing along path...illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

How do I fix the arch to match the circle shape in the background?  LIke is there a way to type along a path but have it be right through the center of the path instead of above or below it?

Comment: Is your type on path circle the same size as the black background circle? It doesn't look like it to me. Or are you using an Arc warp effect on the text?

Comment: Use proportional circles. Your circle for the bottom type is clearly not on a proportional circle.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the response.  Yeah...theyre identical circles.  Its because when you make a circle, the path goes right in the middle of the stroke.  But when you type on a circle path, the words must line up above or below the path - like typing on a line where the line runs above or below the word.

Comment: The bottom type doesn't look like it's on a circle. Looks like it's on an ellipse due to the way the C and S are closer to the white. But.. you can use Baseline Shift in the Character Panel to move type up or down on a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-  Take three circles (same size)

2-  Make one circle stroke 40/ 50 pt. make sure the ‘align stroke centre’ is active.

3-  Write your text on the circle, then go to

Type- type on a path option- pick align to path ‘centre’

4-  Apply this for both circles where the text will appear.

5-  Group two text circles into one after applying vertical and horizontal ‘centre’ alignment

6-  Now align all circles according to vertical and horizontal ‘centre’ alignment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome :)